Count total and matched documents in MongoDB aggregation pipeline?
I have the following MongoDB aggregation pipeline:
    const doc = await Model.aggregate([
      {
        $facet: {
          metadata: [{ $count: 'totalCount' }],
          // data: dataPipeline,
          data: [
            { $match: { 'sysData.status': 'pending' } },
            { $sort: parseSort(req.query.sort) },
            { $project: parseFields(req.query.fields) },
            { $skip: (parsePage(req.query.page) - 1) * parseLimit(req.query.limit) },
            { $limit: parseLimit(req.query.limit) },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: null,
                data: {
                  $push: '$$ROOT',
                },
                filterCount: {
                  $sum: 1,
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ]);

I would like to have the total number of documents with "totalCount", which works correctly. With "filterCount" I would like to have the number of matched documents. Because of the limit stage it will count the number of limited documents which is not correct. How can I resolve this?

Maybe this one.
const doc = await Model.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      metadata: [{ $count: 'totalCount' }],
      pendingdata: [
         { $match: { 'sysData.status': 'pending' } },
         { $count: 'pendingCount' }
      ],
      // data: dataPipeline,
      data: [
        { $match: { 'sysData.status': 'pending' } },
        { $sort: parseSort(req.query.sort) },
        { $project: parseFields(req.query.fields) },
        { $skip: (parsePage(req.query.page) - 1) * parseLimit(req.query.limit) },
        { $limit: parseLimit(req.query.limit) },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            data: {
              $push: '$$ROOT',
            },
            filterCount: {
              $sum: 1,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
]);

Though, the performance may not be the best.
